# Combine a ggplot2 object with a lattice object in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I would like to combine a `ggplot2` with a `lattice` plot object. Since both packages are based on `grid` I was wondering whether this is possible? Ideally, I would do everything in `ggplot2` but I cannot plot a 3d scatter.

So assume I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
mdat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100),
                   cluster = factor(sample(5, 100, TRUE)))
```

First, I want to create a scatterplot matrix in `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtools)
library(plyr)

cols <- c("x", "y", "z")
allS <- adply(combinations(3, 2, cols), 1, function(r)
    data.frame(cluster = mdat$cluster,
          var.x = r[1],
          x = mdat[[r[1]]],
          var.y = r[2],
          y = mdat[[r[2]]]))

sc <- ggplot(allS, aes(x = x, y = y, color = cluster)) + geom_point() +
      facet_grid(var.x ~ var.y)
```

So far so good. Now I want to create a `lattice` 3d scatterplot with all the variables together:

```
library(lattice)
sc3d <- cloud(z ~ x + y, data = mdat, groups = cluster)
```

Now I would like to combine `sc` and `sc3d` in one single plot. How can I achieve that? Maybe with the help of `grid` or `gridExtra` (`pushViewport`, `arrangeGrob`?)? Or can I produce a 3d scatterplot in `ggplot`? Ideally, I would like to see the 3d plot in the empty panel pf the `ggplot` but I guess that's asked even too much, so for starters I would be very happy to learn how we could arrange these two plots side by side.

[image: ggplot]
[image: lattice]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(gridExtra); library(lattice); library(ggplot2)
grid.arrange(xyplot(1~1), qplot(1,1))
```

[image]

You can replace the empty panel by the lattice grob within the gtable, but it doesn't look very good due to the axes etc.

```
g <- ggplotGrob(sc)
lg <- gridExtra:::latticeGrob(sc3d)
ids <- which(g$layout$name == "panel")
remove <- ids[2]
g$grobs[[remove]] <- lg
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!!!!. Any chance that I can place the plot in the empty panel in the ggplot created by `facet_grid`?

Comment: Thanks! Learned a lot and does exactly what I needed!

Comment: Perhaps I should not ask this here, but can you add a .png file to a ggplot with similar techniques (obviously, .png files are not grid based).  Thanks