# Remove inner margins from lattice plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

Thanks to the excellent answer in ["Combine a ggplot2 object with a lattice object in one plot"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328765/combine-a-ggplot2-object-with-a-lattice-object-in-one-plot) and some further thoughts I could plot a `lattice` plot next to a `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(gtools)
library(plyr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1)
mdat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), veryLongName = rnorm(100),
                   cluster = factor(sample(5, 100, TRUE))) 
cols <- c("x", "y", "veryLongName")
allS <- adply(combinations(3, 2, cols), 1, function(r)
    data.frame(cluster = mdat$cluster,
          var.x = r[1],
          x = mdat[[r[1]]],
          var.y = r[2],
          y = mdat[[r[2]]]))

sc <- ggplot(allS, aes(x = x, y = y, color = cluster)) + geom_point() +
      facet_grid(var.x ~ var.y) + theme(legend.position = "top")
sc3d <- cloud(veryLongName ~ x + y, data = mdat, groups = cluster)

scG  <- ggplotGrob(sc)
sc3dG <- gridExtra:::latticeGrob(sc3d)
ids <- grep("axis-(l|b)-(1|2)|panel", scG$layout$name)
scG$grobs[ids[c(2, 5, 8)]] <- list(nullGrob(), nullGrob(), nullGrob())
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(scG)
pushViewport(viewport(0, 0, width = .515, height = .46,
                      just = c("left", "bottom")))
grid.rect()
grid.draw(sc3dG)
```

As you can see in the picture there is quite some margin around the lattice plot and on top of it the axis label for the z-axis is cut (which is not the case is I plot the `lattice` plot alone).

So how can I get rid of this behaviour, thus how to solve the follwing two problems:

1. Get rid of the inner margin between the `viewport` and the `lattice` plot
2. Avoid that the label in the `lattice` plot is cut.

I tried to play with the `clip` option of the `viewport` but without success. So, what to do?

---

**Update 2020**

Edited code and answer to reflect new naming convention in the grob.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

those settings are probably somewhere in `?xyplot`, but I find it's faster to read the internet,

[image]

```
theme.novpadding <-
  list(layout.heights =
         list(top.padding = 0,
              main.key.padding = 0,
              key.axis.padding = 0,
              axis.xlab.padding = 0,
              xlab.key.padding = 0,
              key.sub.padding = 0,
              bottom.padding = 0),
       axis.line = list(col = 0),
       clip =list(panel="off"),
       layout.widths =
         list(left.padding = 0,
              key.ylab.padding = 0,
              ylab.axis.padding = 0,
              axis.key.padding = 0,
              right.padding = 0))


sc3d <- cloud(veryLongName ~ x + y, data = mdat, groups = cluster,
              par.settings = theme.novpadding )

scG  <- ggplotGrob(sc)
sc3dG <- grobTree(gridExtra:::latticeGrob(sc3d), 
                  rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=NA,lwd=1.2)))
ids <- grep("axis-(l|b)-(1|2)|panel", scG$layout$name)
scG$grobs[ids[c(5, 2, 8)]] <- list(nullGrob(), sc3dG, nullGrob())
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(scG)
```

Comment: You did it again!!! Thanks a lot. I have seen the very same post on the internet, but apparently I overlooked the `clip = list(panel="off")` part which finally did the trick. And now I also understand the effects of the `*.padding` arguments in `par.settings`. I will though stick to the additional viewport, as it gives me the opportunity to also plug in a base R graphic. Once more, thanks a lot, very enlighting.